# xlsopen doesn't work in windows 10 Octave 4.0.3

Tags: windows, octave

I am trying to run just the simple code

```
f = xlsopen('Libro1.xlsx');
```

am using octave 4.0.3 in Windows 10, java version 8 update 111 1.8.0_111-b14

From what I have found out so far have:
    already uninstalled it, and installed it again,
    made sure no non ASCII characters are in the path,
    latest java version is installed (not that it matters? supposedly the octave windows installer installs you a version for it) 
    loaded both windows and io pkgs 
    io version 2.4.3 and windows version 1.2.4
    and am still receiving this error:

> warning: fopen: 'C:/Users/tommy/Documents/Octave\Libro1.xlsx' found by searching load path
>   warning: called from
>       xlsopen at line 241 column 7
>       xlsread at line 197 column 11
>       prueba4 at line 2 column 3
>   Detected XLS interfaces: COM*; warning:  No Java support found (no Java JRE? no Java pkg installed AND loaded?)
>
> warning: ActiveX error trying to open or create file C:\Users\tommy\Libro1.xlsx
>   warning: **COM_spsh_open**: some elements in list of return values are undefined
>   file Libro1.xlsx couldn't be unpacked. Is it the proper file format?
>   warning: **OCT_spsh_open**: some elements in list of return values are undefined
>   None.
>   warning: xlsopen.m: no'.xlsx' spreadsheet I/O support with available interfaces.
>   warning: xlsread: some elements in list of return values are undefined
>   d =

Have seen various threads, even one that has the exact same message but, either installing java solved it, or another solution was found but not reported on the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I only see warnings in your posting (no errors) from probing the several interfaces and I guess xlsopen automatically used the OCT interface and `f` is valid afterwards. There are several interfaces to read xlsx using the io package. See [here](http://wiki.octave.org/IO_package). I would suggest the OCT interface which doesn't have dependencies. If you really want a java based interface you've to install a JRE or JDK, have an Octave with java support installed.

EDIT: Now I see that your file Libro1.xlsx isn't located in your working directory and it looks like you've used `addpath` to add the folder where your Libro1.xlsx is located thus the "warning: fopen: 'C:/Users/tommy/Documents/Octave\Libro1.xlsx' found by searching load path".

But "addpath" isn't thought to add directories for fopen. Either `cd` to the directory where your Libro1.xlsx is located (so that you see it listed when executing `ls`) or create a full filename with `fullfile` and use this in `xlsopen`

Comment: I tried forcing the OCT interface but still got the same message

Comment: ans =  1
Checking requested interface(s):
OCT*; (* = default interface)
warning: fopen: 'C:/Octave/Federico/Analisis_Sectorial\Libro1.xlsx' found by searching load path
warning: called from
    xlsopen at line 241 column 7
    xlsread at line 197 column 11
    prueba3 at line 2 column 2
file Libro1.xlsx couldn't be unpacked. Is it the proper file format?
warning: __OCT_spsh_open__: some elements in list of return values are undefined

Comment: warning: xlsopen.m: file type not supported by OCT
warning: xlsread: some elements in list of return values are undefined

Comment: I get the exact same message if I use the code \n   f= xlsread('Libro1.xlsx','Hoja1','A1:A2','OCT');                                                 As far as I understand, f should be equal to the value in cell A1, but I only get an empty array.

Comment: @TomasGaviño: if you see "Libro1.xlsx couldn't be unpacked" make sure it isn't locked from another application (opened by excel) and that it is a valid xlsx. Perhaps you could upload it and provide a link here

Comment: Yeah the file is not open, and the file is just a newly created file with only a 1 in the first cell only for testing purposes.

Comment: See edit, I guess you haven't cd to the location where Libro1.xlsx is located

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Only relevant for Octave version < 3.8.0

I would put this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation

#### Octave java-enabled

Check the output of (from an Octave console) to determine whether you have a Java-capable installation of Octave

```
octave_config_info ("features").JAVA
```

It should return `ans = 1`

#### Check `JAVA_HOME`

And check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

```
getenv('JAVA_HOME')
```

This should be the path to your JRE (e.g. `ans = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91`)

#### Compatible architecture

Is Octave built for the same architecture as the JRE?

From command-line run

```
java -version
```

If it says '64-bit' anywhere, it's 64-bit, otherwise it's 32-bit.

From the Octave terminal

```
octave_config_info('CC')
ans = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

Means Octave it was compiled for 64-bit.

A new Octave session will also display the information `Octave was configured for "x86_64-w64-mingw32"` for the 64-bit version found on the [unofficial file list](http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/octave/Eng/Win/) (*I don't have 32-bit installed, so I can't confirm what the message would be if it's 32-bit*).

Comment: I don't believe this is necessary in Octave 4.0+ (or maybe 3.8+)?

Comment: You are right, the octave-forge java package was included into core with Octave 3.8.0

Comment: @Stephen Wade                                               What if the path is to jdk?                                                                              ans = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102  ?                                                  Still, tried jdk, jre, and even the corresponding bin folders, still same message, with COM and with OCT interface.                                               Should I try POI interface? Think that applies only for linux o mac?

Comment: JDK as path should be fine. Is your Octave built for the same architecture as the JRE/JDK? i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: I think it'd be best if you upload the file somewhere so other people can test whether it's a problem specific to the file.

Comment: It is only a new excel file with a 1 written in the first cell. I don't think the file is the issue.

Comment: You don't think it's the issue or you _know_ it isn't the issue?

Comment: `error: 'octave_config_info' undefined near line 1 column 1`, `error: 'java' undefined near line 1 column 1`. Octave 5.1.0 on Windows 10 64bit.